# listgrid summary grid

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I have a listgrid that I am grouping by the method setGroupByField but I cant see that groups, the method getGroupByFields returns null and then not know why is grouping not if I'm putting the property and the name of field I want to group ... any ideas? here the code.

setGroupByField(CdmsConstants.class_desc)
   setGroupStartOpen(GroupStartOpen.ALL)
   setShowGridSummary(true)
   setShowGroupSummary(true)
   setShowGroupSummaryInHeader(true)

Thanks.

NOTE. i see in the documentation that the method getGroupByFields returns the names of the field(s) by which this grid is grouped, but if is null, thats means that is not grouped..

Comment: im testing the grid and i see that the method getGroupByFields lost the configuration after made a Asynchronous call to RPC ... but i dont know why... some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setGroupByField()` is to use before initialization of listgrid.  If you need to group by after initialization, you have to use `groupBy()`.  Have you tried using `groupBy([yourFieldName])`?

Comment: Erick and I thank you very much fixed the problem, but I was wondering if I can ask you some questions about GWT, you can add you to my messenger contacts?

Comment: I'm not a GWT pro. I started creating smartgwt applications just a while ago but I ran into the same problems as yours when trying to use groups in listgrids. Don't hesitate to post your problems in stackoverflow as most of the time, your questions will be answered !!

Comment: thanks Erik i have a question, its possible to custom the grid summary formula and group summary formula??? that make different things? are this possible?

Comment: I saw your other question but i'm not able to answer that.  I never tried the grid summary sorry